# Mysql count and group by date and location

Tags: php, mysql

This is my current sql query:

```
SELECT t1.location_id, t1.start_datetime, t2.name, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM appointment t1
INNER JOIN location t2
ON t1.location_id = t2.id
GROUP BY t1.location_id, t1.start_datetime
```

The tables mentioned look like this:

```
appointment 
id | start_datetime | location_id 
---+----------------+------------
1  | 2021-06-21     | 2


location 
id | name
---+-----------
1  | Location 1
2  | Location 2
```

I would like the output to look like this where the table headers are the dates and the rows list each location along with how many appointments are booked for each date  :

|  | Date 1 | Date 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Location 1 Name | Number of booked appointments | Number of booked appointments |
| Location 2 Name | Number of booked appointments | Number of booked appointments |

but currently the query produces this output

| location_id | start_datetime | name | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and provide a full [mre]

Comment: @nbk I have added table descriptions. This should be everything needed so this can be reproduced.

Comment: when you read the complete post you see you need also to provide the data that lead to the desied output

Comment: @nbk I have listed the tables and their fields. What goes in them should be self explanatory.

Comment: you query has no date 2 i don't know what you mean by that and i can't see  where the date 2 should come from, so nobody can help you write a create table fill it with data and show us what the exact result must look like

Comment: SELECT t2.`name` as loc_name, t1.start_datetime, COUNT(t1.location_id) AS count
FROM appointment t1
JOIN location t2
ON t1.location_id = t2.id
GROUP BY t1.location_id @kevin I am not sure but try this. in hear I change your GROUP BY to only `location_id` and get count using it

Comment: @nbk I have added some more context

Comment: @sachinkumaraliyanage This didnt work. Please see my original question as I have updated it.

Comment: @sachinkumaraliyanage this is closer to what I want - SELECT t2.name as loc_name, t1.start_datetime, COUNT(t1.location_id) AS count FROM appointment t1 JOIN location t2 ON t1.location_id = t2.id GROUP BY t1.start_datetime but I need the dates to the table headers and the location to not repeat

Comment: @kevin I think you can do that part in PHP

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE appointment (id int ,start_datetime date ,location_id int)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO appointment VALUES (1,'2021-06-01',1),(2,'2021-06-01',1),(3,'2021-06-02',1),
> (4,'2021-06-01',2),(5,'2021-06-02',2),(6,'2021-06-02',2)
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE location  (id int , name varchar(10))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO location VALUES (1, 'loc1'),(2,'loc2')
> ```

> ```
> SET @sql = NULL;
> SELECT
>   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
>                CONCAT('SUM(IF(a.start_datetime = ''', `start_datetime`, ''', 1,0)) AS ''',`start_datetime`,'''')
>               ) INTO @sql
> FROM appointment
> ORDER BY `start_datetime`;
> ```

> ```
> SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT l.`name`,  ', @sql, ' 
>                   FROM appointment a INNER JOIN location l ON l.id = a.location_id 
>                  GROUP BY l.id,l.`name`
>                  ORDER BY l.id');
>
> PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
> EXECUTE stmt;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> name | 2021-06-01 | 2021-06-02
> :--- | ---------: | ---------:
> loc1 |          2 |          1
> loc2 |          1 |          2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0cb0d77df1207fde1d2f0456fe60db1c)*

Comment: Im confused as to how I run this in phpmyadmin

Comment: in a query window start with `SET @sql = NULL;`  and end with `DEALLOCATE PREPARE  stmt;`and then run the **complete** code all of it

Comment: Oh, that worked!. Okay so now how would I take this and put it into a pcp function so I can echo out the table?

Comment: that is a new question a but look for Multi query in mysqli or pdo and copy the hole thing into a string and run it le a normal select query

Comment: I keep getting PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected single-quoted string ", `start_datetime`, "

Comment: see my changed answer in php you put all between 2 double quotes,